# Does $\{ (1, 2, 3, ..., n), (2, 3, ..., n, 1), ..., (n, 1, 2, ..., n-1) \}$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\{(1, 2), (2, 1)\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\{(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2) \}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In general, does $\{ (1, 2, 3, ..., n), (2, 3, ..., n, 1), ..., (n, 1, 2, ..., n-1) \}$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes. Any two consecutive elements have a difference of $(1,1,\ldots,1-n,1,\ldots,1)$. Essentially, all $1$s except for one element. Then, if you add all of the terms together and divide by $\frac{n(n+1)}2$, we get $(1,\ldots,1)$. So, taking $1$ vector and subtracting any of the terms before gives us $(0,0,\ldots,0,n,0,\ldots,0)$. Those are the standard basic vectors.

Comment: @DonThousand Ok. So basically, for each $i$, $\frac{2}{n(n+1)}(v_1 + v_2 + ... + v_n) - (v_{i+1} - v_{i}) = e_k$ for some standard basis vector $e_k$. I.e. we can get all the standard basis vectors via linear combinations, hence we get all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll denote your vectors by $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ where $v_i$ is the one with $1$ in the $i$-th component (e.g. $v_2=(n,1,2,\ldots,n-1)$).

Since we have $n$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, it suffices to prove they're linearly independent. To do this, we put the vectors as the columns of a matrix: $$C:=\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_n\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then $C$ is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), whose rank is $n-d$ where $d$ is the degree of $\gcd(1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+(n-1)x^n,x^n-1)$. This $\gcd$ is $1$, so $d=0$ and thus $C$ has full rank. Therefore, the columns of $C$ are linearly independent.

There are other properties of circulant matrices that allow you to conclude $C$ is invertible (if you don't like the rank approach above).